# How can I save each printed element to then cbind them two by two?

Tags: r, matrix, printing

in R, I´m trying to program a Kronecker product calculator for two matrices(AxB). I´m able to obtain each A subindex product x all of the B matrix elements. This results in four matrices. I need to cbind the first and second matrix, as well as the third and fourth. Then rbind those two resulting matrices.
How could I do that?

```
K = function(A,B){
  nfila = nrow(A)*nrow(B)
  ncolum = ncol(A)*ncol(B)
  m = matrix(NA, nrow = nfila, ncol = ncolum)
  for(j in 1:ncol(A)){
    for(i in 1:nrow(A)){
    
    s = print(A[j,i]*B)
    }
  } 
}

A=matrix(1:4, nrow=2, byrow=TRUE)
B=matrix(5:8, nrow=2, byrow=TRUE)

K(A,B)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a list to store the output.

```
K = function(A,B){
  res <- vector('list', ncol(A))
  for(j in 1:ncol(A)){
    s <- vector('list', nrow(A))
    for(i in 1:nrow(A)){
      s[[i]] = A[j,i]*B
    }
    res[[j]] <- do.call(cbind, s)
  }
  do.call(rbind, res)
}

A=matrix(1:4, nrow=2, byrow=TRUE)
B=matrix(5:8, nrow=2, byrow=TRUE)

K(A,B)

#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,]    5    6   10   12
#[2,]    7    8   14   16
#[3,]   15   18   20   24
#[4,]   21   24   28   32
```

We can also use `lapply` here.

```
K = function(A,B){
  do.call(rbind, lapply(seq(nrow(A)), function(x) 
     do.call(cbind, lapply(A[x, ], `*`, B))))
}
```